# How to resolve issue about Privacy Violation in HPE?

Tags: fortify

We use HPE to check the code potential risks, i got one critical issue below in Log util class
"The method d() in LogUtil.java mishandles confidential information, which can compromise user privacy and is often illegal". 
how can i do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you logging sensitive information, such as credit card numbers, session ids, or names and birth dates?  You should not do so.  You fix the issue by not logging it.